# Concurrent set for C++?

Tags: c++, concurrency, lock-free, concurrentskiplistmap, libcds

I'm looking for a **lock-free** data structure in C++ to replace the following:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(plock);
set.insert(element);
pthread_mutex_unlock(plock);
```

The set should support `.insert()` and `.size()` with at most O(logN) complexity, has an iterator, and should be able to keep its order with a custom comparator. Basically something that does the same as the `ConcurrentSkipListSet` in Java. Ideally, it should be platform independent.

I am looking at CDS: http://libcds.sourceforge.net/doc/cds-api/modules.html but not sure which data structure can achieve the goal. The doc does not really have complexity for some of the data structures.

Any suggestion would be great, thanks!

Comment: what's your platform ? If it's windows you could explore PPL ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504906.aspx ).

Comment: I have to ask what the real problem you're trying to solve is here? It's possible that you could find such a lockfree container...and then have it turn out to be slower than strategically using locks on a normal set.

Comment: Are you sure that `ConcurrentSkipListSet` is lock-free?

Comment: @Jagannath Linux, Mac OS and Windows are our targets.

Comment: @MarkB I have a large graph of millions of integers represented as edge lists, in the format of `sourceNode(int) targetNode(int)`. Given a list of nodes, I need to get all their unique neighbors with multithreading. The neighbor nodes should be kept in the order of the nodes in the list.

Comment: @SiyuanRen I'm pretty sure. The ConcurrentSkipListSet is the alternative of TreeSet for concurrent code

Comment: @Fenwick "Concurrent" is not the same thing as "lock-free".

Comment: @SiyuanRen Of course "concurrent" does not mean "lock-free". I meant CSLSet is designed for concurrent situations to have similar behavior as TreeSet but being lock-free.

Comment: @Fenwick In that case, Intel's TBB can help you here. https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506181 -- The link gives you information about concurrent_unordered_set. Like PPL, they don't support concurrent_set. If you don't require ordering, then this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

With C++11, it's pretty easy to write your own:

```
template <typename T, typename Compare = std::less<T>>
class concurrent_set
{
private:
    set::set<T, Compare> set_;
    std::mutex mutex_;

public:
    typedef typename std::set<T, Compare>::iterator iterator;
    // etc.

    std::pair<iterator, bool>
    insert(const T& val) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        return set_.insert(val);
    }

    size_type size() const {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
        return set_.size();
    }
    // same idea with other functions
};
```

Without C++11, there's `boost::mutex` too.

Comment: Concurrent, perhaps. Lock-free? Now that's the important bit, and as you can see from your code above, std::unique_lock<std::mutex> is ... a lock.The whole point of a lock-free data structure is to avoid locking. Yes, I'm a proud member of Tautology Club.

Comment: Clearly missed that part.